# MySQL - Como Habilitar Federated?

Tags: mysql

Como posso habilitar o federated no mysql no windows e como usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edita seu arquivo  ***/etc/my.cnf*** e adiciona a linha:

```
federated
```

Depois é só reiniciar o servidor.

[Fonte](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/how-to-enable-an-federated-storage-engine-in-the-debian-mysql-package)

Comment: Obrigado consegui habilitar.
Agora quando realizo o comando show engines aparece com suporte = yes, também consegui criar a tabela que eu precisava com a engine federated.

Comment: que bom que resolveu. Pode marcar a resposta como correta?

Comment: Assim que a reputação chegar a 15 eu marcarei. Grande abraço.

Comment: Fala Mauricio, não esquece de mim :)

Comment: Opa ta marcado vlw rsrsrs.

Comment: se não for abusar.. marca como certa :)