# Habilitar federated

Tags: mysql, osx

Preciso habilitar o plugin federated no mysql.
Estou adicionando o federated no meu arquivo my.cnf, quando verifico pelo show engines; diz que não está habilitado.
Estou usando o Mac OSX 10.11 e o mysql 5.2.26. Alguma solução pra isso?

[image: my.cnf]
[image: Show engines;]

Comment: [MySQL - Como Habilitar Federated?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52632/91) e [MySQL Federated](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31293/91)

Comment: Achei uma solução; Adicionei o my.cnf dentro da pasta /etc e já habilitou meu federated.

Comment: Cria uma reposta :)